# node attribute csv igraph

Tags: r, csv, attributes, igraph

I have a large number of adjacency matrices, in csv format exported from excel. I also have a large number of csv. files with vertex attribute data.
I have linked them in SNA but igraph goes further functionally, so I am looking to move to it, but I am failing to be able to build the graph+attribute files.

I am looking to set up some code that will be a workhorse for doing a range of plots.
Although there seem many ways to link these two data sets it seemed this was the simplest:
To make the adjacency matrix in the csv a data frame (cut down for missing vertex data) I use:

```
m <- read.table(header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, textConnection("
      2 3 4 5 6 7 
    2 0 1 1 0 1 0 
    3 1 0 0 0 1 0 
    4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    5 1 0 1 0 0 1 
    6 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    7 1 1 0 1 0 0 
"))
```

In the case of having both vertex and row names in the original file, the imported attributes file has both vertex names and 'row.names' which correspond to the node names. `Hex.ed[1,1]` gives the value of the attribute for the first node in the m network, i.e. node 2:

```
Hex.ed <- read.table(header=TRUE, textConnection("
        HH    Emo  Extra   Aggr Consci    OTE
  2 3.3750 3.0000 3.0000 3.0000 3.0625 3.4375
  3 3.5625 2.9375 3.0625 3.0000 3.3125 3.6250
  4 3.2500 2.8750 3.7500 3.2500 3.8750 3.5000
  5 3.6875 3.1250 3.3750 3.5625 3.6250 3.3125
  6 3.3125 3.0000 3.3125 3.8750 3.2500 3.6875
  7 3.8125 3.2500 3.5625 2.8750 3.6875 3.4375
"))

g <- graph.data.frame(m, directed=TRUE, vertices=Hex.ed)
```

However, I get the error: `Error in graph.data.frame(m, directed = TRUE, vertices = Hex.ed) : Duplicate vertex names`

Answer (score 0):

I get a different error message:

```
Error in graph.data.frame(m, directed = TRUE, vertices = Hex.ed) : 
  Some vertex names in edge list are not listed in vertex data frame
```

but this is because you were not running the example in the question, but used your complete data set, possibly.

Anyway, `graph.data.frame` does not use adjacency matrices. From the docs at http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.data.frame.html:

> ... the first two columns of d are used as a symbolic edge list and
>   additional columns as edge attributes. The names of the attributes are
>   taken from the names of the columns.

If you cared about reading the manual you would have seen an example at the bottom.

If you have an adjacency matrix, then you can use `graph.adjacency` to create the graph, and then add the vertex attribute one by one:

```
g <- graph.adjacency(as.matrix(m))
for (i in seq_len(ncol(Hex.ed))) {
  g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, colnames(Hex.ed)[i], value=Hex.ed[,i])
}
g
# IGRAPH DN-- 6 11 -- 
# + attr: name (v/c), HH (v/n), Emo (v/n), Extra (v/n), Aggr (v/n),
#   Consci (v/n), OTE (v/n)
```

Comment: Many thanks Gabor. I would happily share the csv files, which would make it reproducible, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Hi, I am struggling to make it reproducible on the site and I am not senior enough to post images, but I hope the format of the data is clear.

Comment: I am not sure how reproducible this will be but hopefully you will see enough to spot my error. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: If this is insufficient, I'd be happy to send the csv. files.

Comment: I see. Many thanks. Given that I and perhaps others, may have network and attribute data in a similar format would you suggest this as the most straightforward way of creating the combined igraph file?

Comment: The focus of igraph is large and sparse networks, so most people using it do **not** have the network in an adjacency matrix, imho. I suggest you store your data in an edge list format, because as soon as you'll have a network with 5000 nodes, adjacency matrices become very impractical.